# How to make a variable available in directive when it is set in scope on the controller level?

Tags: angularjs

The controller is below the directive. I am trying to get the language code for the appropriate translation. This is what does it on the controller level.

PaymentPage.get($scope.pageTag)

```
        .success(function(response) {

            $scope.product = response;
            console.log($scope.product);

            // get the language of the product assuming its a valid language code
            var lang_string = $scope.product.language;

            //take the first two letters of the language and honoring the caveat of en-f for example
            var lang = lang_string.substring(0,2);

            // Translate the page guideline
            $translate.use(lang);

            loadCampaigns($scope.product.language);
            initialiseBraintree(braintreeApiKey);
        });
```

However, there is a popover directive just above the controller. The directive looks something like this. I thought I'd be able to retrieve the language code using `$scope.product.language` but I realize that is happening in the controller, so the directive can't access it.

```
.directive('popover', function($translate) {
        // language scope is being set afterwards, must be set before to make use of $translate.use

    //$translate.use('de');

    var mouseOffset = 10;
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            // Returns a promise and must be handled with a .then

            $translate('HOVER_MESSAGE').then(function (popover) {

                console.log(popover);

                var popoverElement = angular.element('<div class="myPopover hide">' + popover + '</div>');

                element.after(popoverElement);

                scope.popoverElement = popoverElement;

            });
```

Also, the directive loads before the controller so other hacks like hiding language code in hidden spans also failed.

Comment: I'd suggest storing your data (`$scope.product`) in a service or factory. And injecting the service into your controller and also  your directive.

Comment: That's my favorite solution to these kinds of things, but in this case I'd be concerned about making sure there was no cross-talk between different instances of the controller scope and the directive sharing the same singleton service.  Hashing would be an answer, I'm just raising it.

Answer (score 1):

I can't try this out just now, but you should be able to use the model to bridge that scope and time gap.  If you bind an attribute of your directive to `product.language` (from `$scope.product.language` in your controller) then it will re-render the directive when the controller provides the language code, and it will be available in the attrs passed to the directive `link()`.

Something like, in your HTML:

```
<button id="buyNowButton" type="submit" popover language="{{product.language}}">
```

In your directive:

```
return {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var lang = attrs.language;
        ...
```

Comment: The `link: function (scope, element, attrs) {` in your directive.  Sorry, would be clearer with a code demo - I'll try to do one soon as I can if it still doesn't make sense.

Comment: Where exactly do you reckon I bind `$scope.product.language` ?

Comment: Is your directive an element or attribute (or class)?

Comment: I added the code, it's just `.directive` , please see sample code in post.

Comment: Sure, what I mean is how do you use the `popover` directive in your HTML?  Is it

an element like `<popover ....\>`
an attribute like `<div popover="..."/>`
a class like `<div class="popover"/>` ?

Comment: Like this `<button id="buyNowButton" type="submit" popover>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76475/discussion-between-ali-gajani-and-randomsock).